# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 & 2008 fails to create project, what other alternative do i have?

Tags: windows

Visual C++ doens't work on my Vista. both 2010 and 2008 fails to create new projects. what alternative do i have ? I am sick of googling and trying out all the other hacks to fix it.

Comment: Try running as administrator?

Comment: Which OS are you running on? Are you using some dodgy pirated version of Visual Studio? What exact errors do you get?

Comment: running on Vista 32bit. Why would i need to pirate Visual Studio when microsoft offers it for free.

Comment: You should describe what happens when you create a new project. I never heard of this kind of problem with VS and Vista (other than the administrator thing) so you must have done something wrong with your installation (like uninstallation of a shared component of those two VS versions...)

Answer (score 1):

What other alternatives? If you're tired of trying the "hacks", I'd be looking at one or more of the following, in no particular order.

- Use a different IDE.
- Re-install Visual Studio.
- Re-install Windows along with all your other apps (including VS).
- Try installing Visual Studio in a newly created virtual machine.
- Upgrade to XP :-)
- Raise a support call with Microsoft.
- Hire someone to fix the problem for you.
- Provide more detail in this question.

Really, the possibilities are (figuratively) endless. There are any number of problems that could be causing this and the detail is a bit light on at the moment. What I tend to do is always have a fresh-install VM of XP lying around so I can test problems in environments that haven't been heavily changed from the originals.

No doubt we will be able to provide more help once the problem has been narrowed down some more. Sorry I can't help more than that at the moment.

Comment: These combos have worked for me dozens of times, and I have had no problems with it like you are describing.  What paxdiablo has said is accurate.  You should also edit your question to add full repro steps and error messages if you want tech support :)

Answer (score 0):

I might guess that you are having trouble creating the projects because you don't have permission to the folder where you're trying to write them.  Try right clicking on Visual Studio and saying 'Run as Administrator' then create the project.

Comment: when i create new project in 2010, it says creating project and nothing happens. in 2008, when i create a project it says invalid string class, and the form builder will not load.

Comment: @gpow, that last symptom sounds very much like a corrupt installation. Time for a re-install, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DevC++ or Eclipse as the compiler perhaps.